# Is MongoDB _id (ObjectId) generated in an ascending order?

Tags: mongodb, objectid

I know how the _id column contains a representation of timestamp when the document has been inserted into the collection. here is an online utility to convert it to timestamp: http://steveridout.github.io/mongo-object-time/

What I'm wondering is if the object id string itself is guaranteed maintain the ascending order or not? i.e. does this comparison always return true?

`"newest object id" > "second newest object id"`

Comment: Wait do you mean insertion order or just _id creation order?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No, there is no guarantee whatsoever. From the [official documentation (at the time of the original answer)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170630170505/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/):

> The relationship between the order of ObjectId values and generation time is not strict within a single second. If multiple systems, or multiple processes or threads on a single system generate values, within a single second; **ObjectId values do not represent a strict insertion order**. Clock skew between clients can also result in non-strict ordering even for values, because client drivers generate ObjectId values, not the mongod process.

And from the [latest docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20200427175829/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/)

> While ObjectId values should increase over time, they are not necessarily monotonic. This is because they:
>
> Only contain one second of temporal resolution, so ObjectId values created within the same second do not have a guaranteed ordering, and
>    Are generated by clients, which may have differing system clocks.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. So turns out it is in ascending order on a wider time range but not in the orders smaller than a second.

Comment: Well, I would be careful, in the worst case scenario "a wider time range" can be really wide. Consider scenario when you insert a document, set system clock to  1 January 1970 and insert another one.

Comment: so...if the ObjectId is generated on one machine, then I can assume they are in an asc order?

Answer (score 9):

For `mongo version >= 3.4`, the Objectid generation is changed a little. 
Its structs are:

- a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
- a 5-byte random value, and
- a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

So the first 4 bytes are still the seconds since the Unix epoch, it is still almost ascending but not strictly.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid

Answer (score 8):

_id: ObjectId(4 bytes timestamp, 3 bytes machine id, 2 bytes process id, 3 bytes incrementer)

This is the id structure. So only last 3 bytes will increment uniquely. So the answer of your question is yes.

Comment: so your answer is partially correct however with the consideration from the answer above it's almost ascending but not strictly since the timestamp bytes have a higher value and it could be out of order in a smaller than 1 second scales.