# Incrementing index in mongo db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

When adding a field called `date` in mongo db, I can do just:

```
date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
```

and it will automatically add `date` field to my new collection when it was created. Is there some way to add a self-incrementing index (`id`) to my collections?

**Note**: I tried to do it on client side, however with every time I push collection with (`id`) field, its being deleted from the collection and replaced with `_id` which is a long string with random characters. Way to long!

Looking for every hints.

Edit: code responsible for adding use to db

```
app.post("/users", function (req, res) {
    createUser(req.body, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json(err);
        }
        return res.json(user);
    });
});
```

Comment: I would also vote for going with the ObjectId instead - it's a supreme concept with a lot of benefits. In order to help you with your problem, I would need to see the code that you use to write your objects to MongoDB.

Comment: @dnickless Ive updated my post :)

Comment: What is in `req.body`?

Comment: @dnickless User info (just a form values)

Comment: I'm just asking because the driver should not simply overwrite your "_id" field *if* you supply it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB automatically makes unique ids for each object in the database, resulting in each entry having a unique _id field being an [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid). You don't really need to worry about specifying custom ids.

You can sort by _id if you want objects roughly in the order they were created, or you could add a date field which is set on creation and sort by that.

Other than that, I'm not sure what you'd gain by having auto incrementing ids

Comment: But I dont want to use that long id in path. Im using a path: `/user/:id`. It will be ridiculous if I'd use it and it would result in a link: `mydomain.com/user/13k4r3f329d3dk`. Looks weird, right? But if it would be something which increments from 0, would be `mydomain.com/user/1`. Looks better, right?

Comment: @Patrickkx: "looks better, right?" - it's not like you'll be typing out these urls by hand (or memorizing them), so it's not clear why would you care too much about this? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Some browsers won't even show that part of the address. Plus, mongodb has a very good reason to use ObjectId as default id type: it is very hard to maintain auto-incrementing sequence in a distributed db.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to implement an auto-increment index but it is not considered a good practice.

Detailed information here: [Auto increment in MongoDB to store sequence of Unique User ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384029/auto-increment-in-mongodb-to-store-sequence-of-unique-user-id)

Check Rizwan Siddiquee answer about how to implement it with a stored javascript function.

Another way would be to implement it on application layer using any kind of ODM but this is obviously dangerous and not so trustable for serious applications.