# Is that possible to use given ObjectID from MongoDB as an entity Id to show on the browser in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, uuid, auto-increment, pojo

As a relational database provides an auto-increment to the id for `entity`. I wonder could we do the same or create another `UID` specifically for that entity. For example, I have a User entity, which using [Mongo driver POJO](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/) and wants to have the `userId` auto-increment it, but [ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384029/auto-increment-in-mongodb-to-store-sequence-of-unique-user-id) advised that is not safe to do as would break the Object ID. So, if I want to use it, how can I use and show each userId with 1...N?

```
    public class User {
    
        private ObjectId id;
    
        @BsonProperty(value = "userId")
        private Long userId;
        private String email;
        private String fullName;
        // private String lastName;
        private String password;
    
    // getter & setter
}
```

Comment: The `ObjectId` _is_ the MongoDB analog to an auto-increment field. (Note that it's not great to use auto-increment for a user ID anyway, since it leaks information and is predictable.) In general, I usually see the `_id` field treated as a `String` in Java and then handled as any opaque identifier.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-  I came across the `_id` of Mongodb that people use String type too. This is where I having trouble to use this object id to be Primary key to work with CRUD e.g. get id for the user using the `_id` and return a `null` value.