# Looking up submissions by ID with MongoDB/Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongoose, database, nosql

So I'm used to looking up submissions by an auto increment primary ID with MySQL, but after using the MongoDB ORM wrapper, Mongoose, I'm finding that since Mongo stores data within collections differently, there is not really any concept of a traditional auto-increment ID.

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to grab a submission now because normally I'd structure my URL like so:

`submission/34/category/slug-goes-here`.

Since the `34` now becomes an ugly string based UUID with Mongo, I don't necessary want to display that in my URLs, but I want a unique URL in order to look up my submissions.

I'm thinking of maybe having a set method that when I insert the submission into my database, it generates some kind of 6 character hash e.g. `zhXk40` and looks it up like that.

I'm wondering if I do it like this what the performance trade-offs would be. If I made constraints on the slug and then looked them up with the slug, and verified that the category matched, would that be more efficient? Either way I'm going to have to check if the category and slug match, but I'm not sure if an ID is even really necessary in this case.

What's the best practice for creating a route + looking up some piece of data from the db based on that route?

Comment: I'd just add a new indexed and unique field to your document that contained an "external id." Use that to look up the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should know is:
**The `_id` property doesn't necessarily is that "ugly" `ObjectId` string.**

Actually, the `_id` just need to be unique within its collection, so if you want to use auto incrementing IDs, there are no problems, however...

If you plan to use sharding within your database, then using auto incrementing field as the `_id` is overkill.

**Why?** Read the accepted answer here: [Should I implement auto-incrementing in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645277/should-i-implement-auto-incrementing-in-mongodb)

In my application, as we're not going to shard it, then we use a indexed, numeric ID just for easier usability to the final user, and internally all references are `ObjectId`s.

Also, here's an good tuto for creating a auto incrementing field in MongoDB: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: Great answer. Good to know that I have this option, but thinking about it more seems to be much more of a pain that I'm interested in. Eventually if I want to take advantage of sharding, it seems like it'll become a pain since I won't know which cluster would have its id incremented. I'll go with just looking it up with its object ID for now. Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

Sheesh!  If we were able to truly know best practice here we'd all be better off.  The talking heads are still talking and will be for some time.

How I would approach this is to go as pretty as I could.  If I had a usable text string to make it semantic that'd be best case.

If I couldn't do that I'd go with the hash thing you suggested.

With both solutions the challenge will be to ensure that it remains unique.  That means lookups before you save.

On performance, it's the same as SQL.  Index what you use to look things up with.  Mongo does good with composite indexes so category name and hash will look up pretty quick.