# .NET, Layered Architecture & MongoDB - What to use as ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm developing a .NET web service while trying to maintain a layered architecture that keeps my Models in one project and DB access (DAL) in a different one. The idea behind this is that if I have to change the DB technology, it's just a matter of creating a differnet DAL, while the rest of the application remains unchanged.

In the data-access layer that I'm developing, I am using  [Mongo DB C# Driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/).

I've seen that:

- Properties named "ID" will be mapped by the C# driver as the database's "_id" (*Convention over configuration*);
- Int + Auto-increment in MongoDB [is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645277/should-i-implement-auto-incrementing-in-mongodb);
- Using Guid's as ID in MongoDB [isn't a good idea either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355792/with-mongodb-and-guids-for-the-id-of-documents-what-is-efficient-way-to-store-th);
- The recommended data type for the ID of documents stored in MongoDB is [`ObjectID`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/). The C# driver provides a class to represent this;

  - However, if I use this data type (from `MongoDB.Bson`) in my Models, then they will become dependent on the MongoDB C# Driver and I don't want that: I want my models to be DB-independent; only my DALs can depend on whatever data access technologies I use.

So what data type should I use for my POCOs' IDs in order to have guarantee uniqueness in the DB? Would a string representation of a Guid be horrible in terms of performance?

Your feedback is welcome.

Comment: Why vote to close this? It's a perfectly reasonable question. Not too specific either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question.

From Experience, I can say that you're right: both GUIDs and auto-increment aren't the best idea (with GUID being a lot better than auto-increments), but not only for the reason mentioned in the SO question you linked to, but mostly because you need to be aware of the implications of monotonic vs. non-monotonic keys.

With the `ObjectIds`, I see three options:

- Map between domain model and DAL. In the domain model, you could use the objectid's string representation. That's a bit annoying, but it forces you to separation of concerns.
- Use your own data type and implement a type converter / mongodb serializer. I haven't tried that but I don't see why this wouldn't work.
- Accept the MongoDB dependency. After all, if you *really* swap out your database, that will be a ***huge*** task. Different databases have very different characteristics and require very different data models. The whole "swap out the database" in a minute is bogus IMHO, it's never that easy and a database is a much leakier abstraction than anyone wants to admit. Trying to keep independent is a PITA. Anyway, doing a seek-and-destroy on the word `ObjectId` will be less than 1% of the other work.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm not actually trying to achieve a "swap out the DB for (ANY) other DB" fantasy: in this scenario, it's likely that the DB of choice will be either MongoDB or SQL Server. 

In this case, swapping one for the other would 'only' mean implementing a new DAL library, obeying some core interfaces. While that does indeed require some work, I believe I wouldn't need to change the domain models.

So I'll probably go for the first option.