# The right way to create an auto increment ID on Prisma using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, prisma

I'm trying to create an auto increment ID with Prisma, but the autoincrement() function doesn't exist with mongodb as data-source.

```
model User {
  id        String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  sequence  Int      @unique @default(autoincrement()) // This doesn't work with mongodb
  email     String   @unique
  password  String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

I know I can make a query to check the last sequence but this seens to be too expensive to do.

There is a better way to this?

Like in prisma.user.create() there is a way to get the last sequence field (like we do with mongoose)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB connector for prisma doesn't support `autoincrement()`. `autoincrement()` is only supported by the relational database connectors. See the Prisma [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#defining-ids-in-mongodb) that explains this.
You can also view a previous discussion related to this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645277/should-i-implement-auto-incrementing-in-mongodb/14433131)

Comment: You're totally right, but there is a way to create a autoincrement id directly from mongo console. 

https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-auto-increment